# How to attach and show image in mail using php?

Tags: php, html, image, email, email-attachments

I want to **attach** an image and then show it in an email.

The image I want to attach is on my server. I use html in the email.

How do I do this with php? (And I **don't** want to **use** any **library** like PEAR).