# insert image in mail body

Tags: html, phpmailer, php

How to insert image in mail body when user click on send button. I am using php mail

Comment: Can you paste in the code you have so far please?

Comment: Are you using the php `mail()` function?  If so, I think that it is HTML mail, which I believe could use the `<a>` tag.

Comment: I will suggest you to go for phpmailer or swiftmailer for sending mails.

Comment: Don't you normally want to send the mail instead of add an image when clicking a "send mail" button?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606588/how-to-attach-and-show-image-in-mail-using-php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [base64 encoded images in email signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

To create an HTML email you can do something like this:

```
...
$message = "<html><head></head><body>";
$message .= "<img src='link-image.jpg' alt='' /></body></html>";

$headers = "From: $from_email";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This should build an HTML email for you and you should then be able to insert just normal html.

**edit**
You can read more about how to create HTML emails using PHP from here: http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

Comment: I tried this, and it worked however. You need to add the absolute path. Like http://www.example.com/image.jpg And nog just image.jpg

Answer (score 7):

If you are actually asking: How to attach and insert inline images in a html email? you can use this for guidance :) https://www.quora.com/What-is-meant-by-inline-images-in-HTML

In that example, pay extra attention to how the src attribute of the img tag is filled (the "cid" is actually the id given as "Content-ID:" for the image attachment header).

Hope this helps, all the best...

Comment: I don't see any mention of "cid" or "Content-ID" on the linked page. For reference, see [`Content-ID` @ How to embed images in email](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4312865/924299).

Answer (score 4):

To insert image in body of mail, you can use phpmailerclass which links are

http://www.phpclasses.org/package/264-PHP-Full-featured-email-transfer-class-for-PHP.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/phpmailer/

Answer (score 1):

The correct is almost as the above marked answer. One most important part omitted is **the absolute part of the image** as indicated below:

```
$message = "<html><head></head><body>";
$message .= "<img src='http://example.com/images/link-image.jpg' alt='' /></body></html>";

$headers = "From: $from_email";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```