# Display images in email using mail() in PHP

Tags: php, image, email

How do I display images in an email using the `mail()` function in PHP?

Does putting `<img src="image path" />` work?

Comment: Do you want to attach image with the email? or you could use any image residing on web. If the image is on Web, just use the <IMG> Tag

Comment: Right here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390138/insert-image-in-mail-body

Comment: You also already posted this last week: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787206/php-strange-email-sending-issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the headers to tell it that it's HTML. You can do this by:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

and then send with

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

so you pass the headers as a string to the 4th parameter of `mail()`.

You should set the relevant character encoding in `charset`, and also provide a text version if this is going to end users.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending the mail as html. Look at this 
http://www.webcheatsheet.com/PHP/send_email_text_html_attachment.php