# embedded html powershell email compressing length of pic

Tags: html, email, powershell

I have a powershell script that embedds (not attaches) a picture and sends an email. The picture has increased now to 1500x5000 pixels and now I'm seeing that the pictures lenth gets compressed and it distorts the picture. How ever, when I manually insert the picture via outlook and send an email, it looks fine.

If i save the picture and then open it via paint or something, the picture opens fine. It just looks compressed in the email. Anyone know what may be going on there?

```
{
    $Application = "C:\Autobatch\Spotfire.Dxp.Automation.ClientJobSender.exe"
    $Arguments  = "http://s.net:8070/spotfireautomation/JobExecutor.asmx C:\Autobatch\HourlyStats.xml"
    $CommandLine = "{0} {1}" -f $Application,$Arguments
    invoke-expression $CommandLine
    $file = "C:\Autobatch\HourlyStats.png"
    $smtpServer = "smtp.staom.sec.s.net"
    $att = new-object Net.Mail.Attachment($file)
    $att.ContentType.MediaType = “image/png”
    $att.ContentId = “pict”
    $att.TransferEncoding = [System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding]::Base64
    $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)
    $msg.Attachments.Add($att)
    $msg.From = "d.k@s.com"
    $msg.To.Add("r.p@p.com")
    $msg.Subject = "Voice and Data Hourly Stats"
    $msg.Body = "<p style=’font-family: Calibri, sans-serif’>
              Voice and data hourly stats details<br />
             </p>
             <img src='cid:pict'/>"
    $msg.IsBodyHTML = $true
    $smtp.Send($msg)
    $att.Dispose()
    invoke-expression "DEL $file"
}
```

here is what the picture looks like in the email.

[here is what the picture looks like in the email.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJiwR.png)

s this an SMTP issue? If I right click on the pic in the email and save it and then open with preview, it looks fine. This is odd to me, why is it showing up compressed in the email then?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJiwR.png)

EDIT: Updated code block

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534364/embedded-html-powershell-email-compressing-pic-length#new-answer                                                                                                                                      please go through this link as this is also same case

Comment: Please don't open duplicates of your own questions.