# embedded image in html body of powershell email compressed pic length

Tags: html, email, powershell

I am using below script for sending a mail.

```
{

$imgfile = “C:\Users\Rammy\Desktop\Pic.png”
$SMTPServer = “smtp.gmail.com”
$SMTPPort = “587”
$Username = “motheramesh486@gmail.com”
$Password = “xxxxxxxx”

$to = “motheramesh486@gmail.com”
$cc = “motheramesh486@gmail.com”
$subject = “Email Subject”
$body = @”
<html>
<body>
<img src="cid:image1.png">
</body>
</html>
“@

$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment($imgfile)

$attachment.ContentDisposition.Inline = $True
$attachment.ContentDisposition.DispositionType = “Inline”
$attachment.ContentType.MediaType = “image/png”
$attachment.ContentId = ‘image1.png’

$message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage
$message.subject = $subject
$message.IsBodyHtml = $True

$message.body = $body
$message.to.add($to)
$message.cc.add($cc)
$message.from = $username
$message.attachments.add($attachment)

$smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
$smtp.EnableSSL = $true
$smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,         $Password);

$smtp.send($message)
write-host “Mail Sent”

$attachment.Dispose();
$message.Dispose();
}
```

I am able to send the mail using above script but it compressed pic length.
The picture has  1500x5000 pixels and now I'm seeing that the pictures length gets compressed and it distorts the picture.
How ever, when I manually insert the picture via outlook and send an email, it looks absolutely fine.

If i save the picture and then open it via paint or something, the picture opens fine. It just looks compressed in the email. Anyone know what may be going on there?

[Click here to see how the image looks like in mail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ucMI.png)

[Click here for original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Z1RV.jpg)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [embedded html powershell email compressing pic length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534364/embedded-html-powershell-email-compressing-pic-length)

Comment: You posted this question already (about 6 hours before this post), and it was already closed as a duplicate with a link to where you can find the answer.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Do you have an example png with which it happens?

Comment: I have added the original and after images.