# HTML Email Signature on iOS - Images are not displaying.

Tags: html, ios, iphone, html-email, signature

I have created an HTML email signature using the usual tables and inline styling.

There is also one image attachment of a logo. It displays perfectly in all email clients.

However when I try and make an iPhone/iPad signature I have problems:

The image displays ok, for a couple of hours and then just drops away and a little box with a cross displays instead.

Does anyone have any ideas why this might be?

Comment: look like the image deleted from server. otherwise there is no way image disappear after few hours.

Comment: Try hosting the image online - something like `http://yoursite.com/image.jpg`. That way you can reference it and it will not vanish.

Comment: The image is hosted online, on the same server I host my website, but it still disappears. @John.

Comment: Maybe try [base64 encoding](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter) it in there, that way it is baked into the html. More reference [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures?rq=1)

Answer (score 6):

It’s a little tricky to setup an email signature with an image on iPhone or iPad. If you simply copy and paste a signature, the image will work at first but after some time, it will become missing and will just show up as a blank box instead of your image in your html email signature.

Here is the solution that worked for me. Hope it helps you.

**PREPARE THE HTML SIGNATURE.**

1. Create an html signature with an image that points to your server
2. Save the .html file and email it to yourself.

Sample HTML email signature with image for iPhone/iPad http://vitworks.com/html-email-signature-with-an-image-on-iphoneipad/

**HOW TO SETUP EMAIL SIGNATURE WITH AN IMAGE ON YOUR IPHONE.**

1. On your iPhone open the email that contains the email-signature.html
2. Tap on the html file to open it
3. Press and hold anywhere on the screen
4. Then choose Copy
5. Press the home screen
6. Go to Settings
7. Scroll down and choose “Mail, Contacts, Calendars”
8. Then Scroll down and tap on Signature
9. Delete your current email signature
10. Press and hold till you get a menu
11. Choose paste
12. This is very important step: Make sure to **shake your phone from side to side**
13. Choose undo (This removes the extra spacing and formatting that the iPhone automatically adds to your signature.
14. Tap anywhere on the white space to unselect
15. Now edit the signature with your information
    (make sure to completely remove the default phone numbers and type them in again to make sure that the numbers are not blue.
16. Tap the Back Button

**To test is out**

Go to Mail and create a new email. Your email signature with an image will automatically show up on the bottom of your emails on your iphone.

Comment: This is a lifesaver!

Comment: Step 12 was the solution for my signature being messed up for so long. Thanks for the brilliant advice.

Answer (score 1):

If the signature was edited and graphic information in Outlook's editor was changed at all, it sometimes will download the graphics and refer to them differently in the file. If you copy and paste that to your iPhone then, it breaks and loses the graphics because it looks for them locally.

Check to see if there is a folder in your %appdata%\microsoft\signatures folder that matches your signature name. If the graphics are stored in that folder, it's a good bet something happened to your hosted hyperlinks. Outlook likes to change those to local at times.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this 4 years on.

When you select your signature and hit copy then paste it into the 'signature' area on ios you need to ensure its copied everything.

Sometimes it looks like its copied everything when in fact its cut off the end of a table or other code.

The only way I could get this to work was to add

`<p>your name</p><br><br>`

**your signature content**

`<br><br><p>end</p>`

Copy the entire signature, with the extra code. Paste it into the mail signature box and delete the word 'end'. Don't delete any other spaces.

Apple. Nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Is the image stored on a remote server?  If so it may be that your iDevice is not connected to a network (WIFI or 3G).  Eg: When you're in the office/at home its on your local WIFI and then when you move away it has no signal and therefore no way to download the image when you compose a new email.

Comment: It is stored in the same place I host my website. It drops off even when I am at home and my phone is connected with WIFI.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my HTML signature images would not show up.

I copy pasted the html content in the email signature and sent an email to my gmail account and pictures showed up. So, I downloaded gmail app for ios, I coppied the signature from that email that I sent to my self with showing pitures.

Then I pasted it into the signature part and surprisingly it worked!!

I don't know why iPhone cannot pick it up itself, but I think when you copy the html file and paste it in the signature place, it does not copy all of the html code or something will be missing. But, when you copy it from an email on the Gmail app on IOS, it will copy the html because gmail plain is html.

Let me know if it works for you too.