# The precise format of Content-Id header

Tags: email, mime

I'm really confused when it comes to the format of `Content-Id` headers in message parts.

It seems to me that only [RFC 2045](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2045#section-7) covers the format of the header, however briefly:

> In constructing a high-level user agent, it may be desirable to allow
> one body to make reference to another.  Accordingly, bodies may be
> labelled using the "Content-ID" header field, which is syntactically
> identical to the "Message-ID" header field:
>
> ```
>  id := "Content-ID" ":" msg-id
> ```
>
> Like the Message-ID values, Content-ID values must be generated to be
> world-unique.

[RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.6.4) explains the format of a `msg-id` token like so:

> The message identifier (msg-id) is similar in syntax to an angle-addr
> construct without the internal CFWS.
>
> message-id      =       "Message-ID:" msg-id CRLF
>
> in-reply-to     =       "In-Reply-To:" 1*msg-id CRLF
>
> references      =       "References:" 1*msg-id CRLF
>
> msg-id          =       [CFWS] "<" id-left "@" id-right ">" [CFWS]
>
> id-left         =       dot-atom-text / no-fold-quote / obs-id-left
>
> id-right        =       dot-atom-text / no-fold-literal / obs-id-right
>
> no-fold-quote   =       DQUOTE *(qtext / quoted-pair) DQUOTE
>
> no-fold-literal =       "[" *(dtext / quoted-pair) "]"

Long story short: it includes the at ('@') symbol, just like the `Message-Id` header of a message. However, almost all reader-friendly articles on MIME format give examples of `Content-Id` **without** the at symbol (including not-really-global identifiers like `myimagecid` or `inlineimage001` as well as randomly generated UUIDS without the at symbol). They would surely stress the importance of the '@' symbol if that would be necessary, just like they do with the `Message-Id` header, right? Right?

I've run some tests on real-world email clients and see how they compose emails with embedded inline images:

- Thunderbird generates identifiers with the at symbol. Example: `part1.12345678.12345678@domain.example.com`
- Gmail generates identifiers *without* such symbol and with no domain part. Example: `ii_abc1234x0_12345ab12abcdefa`

I didn't test any more email clients (if someone did, it'd be great to complete the list above), but these two already show the striking difference. Google not obeying RFC standards? It sure looks smelly and I want to know whether that's because I missed something, or because the format isn't really that important after all (which in the long run feels rather disturbing). I'm also interested in checking how many popular email clients actually discard the 'at' symbol.

Comment: Obsoleted by RFC 5322.

Comment: [RFC 2392](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2392.txt) defines CID and MID URLs.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Go by what the spec says, not by what some mail clients do.

So yes, a `Content-Id` header should have a value that conforms to the way the specification says and therefor should have an '@' symbol.

The world of email is a broken hell hole of many different mail clients and servers doing their own thing and not respecting the standards.

As someone who has written mail software for the past 17 years, I can assure you, this is not the only place that Google deviates from the specs.

Comment: Specifications sure come handy when composing mails. When I'm parsing incoming mail though, I have to be fully aware of what violations of the standard are by design (Gmail) or are intended to be malicious (spam) and act accordingly. I can't simply reject every email not matching the specs. Now taking advantage of your 17 year experience in managing this mad house, could you please expand on your answer and tell me, what other parts of the specs are likely to be violated by email clients/servers? I'm also very curious what other specs Google violates (it doesn't have to be mail related).

Comment: I ranted a bit about parsing address headers back in 2013 http://jeffreystedfast.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-decoding-rfc2047-encoded-headers-is.html and then discovered a Thunderbird developer who was ranting (much more eloquently than myself) about similar issues with email which you can find at http://quetzalcoatal.blogspot.com/ - he's got an entire series of blog posts that I'd highly recommend reading if you are interested in implementing a MIME parser or even just email address parsers.

Comment: The other GMail deviations from mail specs that I've discovered have been wrt their IMAP implementation. For example, they did not handle the `ALL`, `FAST` or `FULL` aliases defined for use with the `FETCH` command a few years ago (maybe that's fixed now, I'm not sure). GMail's IMAP server implementation breaks when it encounters nested multiparts with the same boundary and returns a `BODYSTRUCTURE` like the example in https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit/issues/205 - while annoying from an IMAP client perspective, I actually understand and sympathize with Google on this issue.

Comment: Other examples include some oddities in GMail IMAP's representation of `group` addresses in their `ENVELOPE` response and the fact that they allow `]` characters in places where they are expressly forbidden in the IMAP spec.

Comment: My advice to you if you are implementing parsers for MIME (and related) technologies is this: start by implementing the spec as closely as you can. Then do some real-world testing and as you discover oddities in widely-used software, tweak your parser(s) to deal with those oddities as they are discovered. You can't design a parser to deal with interoperability issues that you don't know exist, but you *can* design a parser to deal with the specifications. As your knowledge grows based on real-world experience, you'll be able to tweak your parsers to handle the madness you discover.

Comment: What you've just written is **pure gold**. Thank you for giving so much valuable resources on the subject. The more I delve into those materials however, the more astonished I am of what the standards like MIME or IMAP have actually become and wonder: "when and why did all of this go so wrong? It's just a spec everyone should follow, like any other. Why did no one scold those rascals for not following it and introducing chaos in the first place?". I've already started reading the series on quetzalcoatal.blogspot.com and it's a great read. Perhaps it will answer this question shortly. Cheers!

Comment: FWIW, this got me thinking and I remembered that there was an RFC that had some recommendations for some common suckage: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7103 - you may find that useful. You might also find the source code for my MIME parser useful: https://github.com/jstedfast/MimeKit