# PHP: Send base64 image via email

Tags: php, email

I am asking this question because I didn't find clear answer to this question though it's been asked many times.

I am generating **base64 png** code on runtime by using literallycanvas library. Instead of saving that image on server, I want to send it via email.

```
function mailCanvasImage($contactMail, $imageSrc){

        $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Cc: myname@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

        $message = "<html><head><title>Your email at the time</title></head><body><img src=\"" . $imageSrc . "\" alt=\"Canvas Image\"><br><strong>Contact Email: </strong>" . $contactMail . "</body>";


        if( mail('myname@gmail.com', 'Canvas Layout Image', $message, $headers) ){
            return true;
        }else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

My base64 code looks like below and displays well if I just output it but when I send it in email, it shows empty image.

```
data:image\/png;base64,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
```

I have read in some articles that using cid method can resolve this issue but there are no clear instructions on how to do it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110164/6642415 This is the answer you seek

Comment: @Luke Thanks for looking into it, but I have one confusion. The code seems like comments, as there is no php or anything. Will it work if I just copy and paste the code on my file?