# Laravel Response base64 data to image

Tags: laravel

I have image in base64 encoded string format.
I want to return image through URL in laravel
I used following code but not working

```
return response('data:image/png;base64,'.$logo)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png'); //not working 

return response($logo)->header('Content-Type', 'image/png');//not working
```

I don't want image like this: `<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$logo.'">` because image need to show in email body.

Comment: have you tried `<img src=URL`?

Comment: Yes, but not working

Comment: According to this answer it is not recommended to use base64 encoding for images in emails because some clients won't show it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110167/4776831

Comment: Yes thats why i want to convert base64 image to URL response

Answer (score 1):

```
    $thumbData = explode(';base64,', $thumb);
    $imageType = str_replace('data:', '', $thumbData[0] ?? '');
    $thumbData = $thumbData[1] ?? '';
    $imageStream = base64_decode($thumbData);
    return \Response::stream(function() use($imageStream) {
        echo $imageStream;
    }, 200, ["Content-Type"=> $imageType]);
```