# Nodemailer doesn't find any images but finds text

Tags: html, node.js, nodemailer

I try to create a personnalized template  and send automated message with this templates.

I use nodemailer so i use nodeJs, and i have created an html template. The text appears on the mail but the image does not.

[image]

I followed a tutorial, and there is my .handlebars where i do my html (pictures are real, i pasted one in the same folder)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Formulaire</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/mail.css">


</head>
<body>
    <div class='txt2'>
        <div>
        <img class='logo_synapture' src="logosynapture.png">  
        </div>
        

        <div>
            <img class='logo_hackathon' src="escape.png">  
        </div>

       </div>

    
    <div class='txt'>
     <h1>Merci d'avoir rejoint notre Hackathon</h1>
  
    </div>

    

    <div class='cordonnees'>
        <div>
 
        </div>
    </div>

    
</body>
</html>
```

and there is my .js

```
/*
    Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38aE1lSAJZ8
    Don't forget to disable less secure app from Gmail: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps TODO:
*/

require('dotenv').config();

const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const hbs = require('nodemailer-handlebars');
const log = console.log;


// Step 1
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    auth: {
        user: 'mail', // TODO: your gmail account 
        pass: 'mdp' // TODO: your gmail password
    }
});

// Step 2
transporter.use('compile', hbs({
    viewEngine: 'express-handlebars',
    viewPath: './views/'
}));


// Step 3
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'hacktonthon@gmail.com', // TODO: email sender
    to: 'mail.com', // TODO: email receiver
    subject: 'Nodemailer - Test',
    text: 'Wooohooo it works!!',
    template: 'index',
    context: {
        name: 'Accime Esterling'
    } // send extra values to template
};

// Step 4
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        return log('Error occurs');
    }
    return log('Email sent!!!');
});
```

I don't understand what the problem could be, I searched on internet but there are not a lot of answers.

I don't think nodemailer can't read img, but did I forget something?
And if it can't, how can I send images?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Embed image in email body nodemailer nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449379/embed-image-in-email-body-nodemailer-nodejs)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you should notice here is: where did you put these images? The images src is pointing to a root folder.
I think that the possibilities for your 404 in the images could be:

- The directory is not public, so the images cannot be found in the request
- You are pointing the wrong path in the src

Even if you are working with mail protocols, basically the requests are http(s) and need to search for a valid address in your server (or a CDN) to fetch the content you are trying to show.

Comment: Hello,  thanks for your answer, logo_synapture.png , escape.png and index.handlebars are in the same folder.