# Access images in public folder from pages/api in nextJS using nodemailer

Tags: next.js, serverless, nodemailer

using these versions

```
"next": "12.0.7"
"nodemailer": "^6.7.2"
```

I am building a mailing service using NextJS, but i encountered some problems:

- gmail not rendering the images (solved by sending as attachment the images i want to render)
- In production, the mailing service can't find the images inside the public folder
- Mails sent in dev environment work perfect, but in production the images don't render

I have the following structure

```
pages
   -api
       -contact.js
public
   -images
       -image_name.png
```

in contact.js

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48449379/embed-image-in-email-body-nodemailer-nodejs)

```
...

 mailData = {
                from: process.env.THE_EMAIL,
                to: req.body.email,
                subject: `SOME_SUBJECT`,
                attachments: [
                    {
                        filename: 'image_name.png',
                        path: 'public/images/image_name.png',
                        cid: 'SOME_ID_FOR_NODEMAILER',
                    }
             ]}

...
```

When Im working in localhost, the mailing service works perfect and the images are found, but when is in production (deployed with Vercel) it cannot find the images.

Any thoughts or alternatives?
Should i host the images in a CDN and forget about it?

Comment: Can -you- not find them or can your software not find them?

Comment: the software cant find them, i get an error that the system cant find the file

Comment: Have you checked the owner \ permissions?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Next.js: How to get static assets from within getStaticProps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65860421/next-js-how-to-get-static-assets-from-within-getstaticprops)? Try using `path.join(process.cwd(), 'public/images/image_name.png')` as the image's path.

Comment: hey i have the same issue, did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me, following [this article](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-static-props#reading-files-use-processcwd:%7E:text=Reading%20files%3A%20Use%20process.cwd())

```
const mailOptions = {
  from: 'fromEmailAddress@gmail.com',
  to: email,
  replyTo: email,
  subject: `${emailSubject}`,

  html: emailBody,
  attachments: [
    {
      filename: `invoice-${invoiceNumber}.pdf`,
      path: process.cwd() + '/public/invoice.pdf'
    }
  ]
}
```