# Images not loading properly in gmail using html template (on Samsung Galaxy Note 5)

Tags: html, email

I have created one html template for email. (using `PHP` and `PHPMailer` to send the mail)

It's working fine in below sizes.

- Large Screen Display (LG)
- Medium or Normal Screen Display and Laptops (MD)
- Tablets Screens (SM)
- Mobile Devices Screens (XS)
- Working in Outlook as well

But it's not working in **Samsung Galaxy Note 5**.

In other **android devices** looks like below image,

[image]

In **Samsung Galaxy Note 5** looks like below,

[image]

Images displayed like attached items in **Samsung Galaxy Note 5**.

**Html Code**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>A Simple Responsive HTML Email</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .content {max-width: 900px !important;}
      .dynamic_container{width: 31.33% !important;border:1px solid #ccc;margin:1%;}
      a{padding: 10px 8px !important;}
      
      @media (min-width:651px) and (max-width: 992px){
      .content {max-width: 600px !important;}
      .dynamic_container{width: 47% !important;margin:1.5%;}
      a{padding: 10px 0 !important;}
      }
      @media (min-width:0px) and (max-width: 650px){
      .content {max-width: 300px !important;}
      .dynamic_container{width: 96% !important;border:1px solid #ccc;margin:2%;}
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body bgcolor="#f6f8f1" style="margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; min-width: 100% !important;">
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      <style>
        .dynamic_container{width: 32.6% !important;border:1px solid #ccc;}
        .button{padding:10px !important;}
      </style>
      <table width="100%" align="center" border="0">
        <tr>
          <td>
    <![endif]-->
    <table class="content" align="center" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="header" bgcolor="#c7d8a7" style="padding: 40px 30px 20px 30px;">
          <table width="100" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td height="70" style="padding: 0px 20px 20px 0px;">
                <img src="assets/images/i4cfinancial_Logo.png" border="0" alt="" style="height: auto;" />
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="innerpadding borderbottom" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #f2eeed;">
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
          <table class="dynamic_container" width="100%" align="left" border="0" style="margin-bottom:5px;">  
            <tr>
              <td>
                <table width="100%" border="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td colspan="2" class="comment_text" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;font-size: 13px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
                      Recent weeks have seen prices trending up strongly. In recent sessions the uptrend has been strong. There are indications that this instrument is short-term overbought. The last session close was an outlier to the upside.
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Power Grid / Tradability </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid_header" style="color: #153643; font-family: sans-serif;">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 15px; line-height: 22px;padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">Recent Price Action</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr class="grid">
                    <td colspan="2" style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                      <img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;">
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td style="padding: 20px 0px 0px 0px;">
                      <table class="buttonwrapper" width="100%" align="center" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="50" valign="middle">
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Learn More...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td class="button" width="100%" style="background-color: #556401;text-align: center; font-size: 18px; font-family: sans-serif; font-weight: bold; padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;">
                            <a width="100%" href="#" style="background-color: #556401;border: 0 none;color: #fff;display: block;text-decoration: none;">Guess to win...</a>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="footer" bgcolor="#44525f" style="padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;">
          <table width="100%" border="0">
            <tr>
              <td align="center" class="footercopy" style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff;">&copy; Someone, somewhere 2013<br/><a href="#" class="unsubscribe" style="display: block; margin-top: 20px; padding: 10px 50px; border-radius: 5px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold;"><font color="#ffffff">Unsubscribe</font></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding: 20px 0 0 0;">
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%" align="right" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                      <a href="http://www.facebook.com/">
                        <img src="assets/images/fb.png" width="37" height="37" alt="Facebook" border="0" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                    <td width="50%" align="left" style="padding: 0 10px 0 10px;">
                      <a href="http://www.twitter.com/">
                        <img src="assets/images/twit.png" width="37" height="37" alt="Twitter" border="0" />
                      </a>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <![endif]-->
  </body>
</html>
```

Can you please help me (Explain as well) ?

Comment: Is this is the latest gmail client on that phone?

Comment: Yes.... Updated one...

Comment: Seems like you are not the first one [this](https://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-6/555831-seriously-no-inline-images-email-android.html), [this](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/sCro7680KW0), [this](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/433672-inline-images-not-displaying-gmail-android.html)

Comment: Yes, You are right. But the android devices having low density like mdpi, hdpi working fine.
If its increases not working properly.

Comment: @TarunLalwani,  And One thing you need to remember i have done with mail template in html. (not uploading the images inline...)

Comment: That is actually a interesting point. Can you view the raw the message and make a pastebin of the same?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please make it more clear.

Comment: Like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1mS3.png)

Comment: Updated code from show original text (Gmail)...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169145/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-sarvan-kumar).

Comment: @SarvanKumar Could you please try the approach given in my answer below and let me know if it works? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The images in an email template might not display for a variety of reasons. The first thing to check is that the email client is enabled to display images. you might refer to your email client below to adjust your settings:

[iPhone/iPod/iPad](https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/5554-images-not-displaying-in-an-email-client?lang=en_US#iOS)

[Gmail](https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/5554-images-not-displaying-in-an-email-client?lang=en_US#Gmail)

If the settings in your email client are correct and you still can't view images:

- Try opening your email in another web browser or unblock images in
  the browser.
- Sometimes the image is just too large or in a format that the email
  client doesn't support; the most common formats are JPG, PNG and GIF.
- Make sure the images are hosted on a public web server. If you need a
  password to access the image, they won't display in an email.

In addition to it would be better to have a look at the articles below in order to prevent images from showing in an email template:

[Set Up Images for Success in an Email](https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/5619-set-up-images-for-success-in-a-campaign-email?lang=en_US)

[Missing Images in an Email Campaign](https://knowledgebase.constantcontact.com/articles/KnowledgeBase/6327-missing-images-in-an-email-campaign?lang=en_US)

Comment: I have tried your steps its working for email generated from php. But if i forward that email to some other person it doesn't work in that device (samsung note 5)...
Can you please help me further..

Comment: @SarvanKumar Sure... What about the other devices? Have you tried with other devices i.e iPhone? On the other hand can you display the email in MS Outlook properly? If you can't, the problem may be related to Outlook rather than the devices.

Comment: Others works fine, Like outlook (in all versions of it), iPhone, iPod, iPad Mini, iPad...

Comment: Tested some android devices as well... that also works fine. (FYI, forwarded email also make these issues).

Comment: @SarvanKumar Are you sure that "Show Images" option is switched on as explained on [Galaxy S7 Edge: Choose whether to show images in Email](https://webcazine.com/18403/galaxy-s7-edge-choose-whether-to-show-images-in-email/)? The problem may be related to Android rather than device. So, it is worthy to have a look at [Inline Images Not Displaying In Gmail on Android](https://forums.androidcentral.com/ask-question/433672-inline-images-not-displaying-gmail-android.html)...

Comment: I have checked all the above pages already.
I think there might be android or gmail client issue on that particular devices (high resolutions devices using hdpi or xhdpi or xxhdpi)...

Comment: If the email directly generated its works fine. But if its forwarded to some one is affecting the style sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

What about converting the images to base64?

You'll result with a slightly increased email size but you'll be able to show the images without showing them as attached ones.

Small guide on how to use base64 in emails: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110167/9295292

Comment: gmail max email size is 102kb or something like that, which is not enough for most images, maybe a small logo or 2

Comment: base64 have many issues regarding web mail clients, apple mail, mobile mail clients etc.
It's really no option..

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about this since i've never encountered something like this when i make emails and i make alot daily. Try changing the source of the img to a location instead and not as an included /assets/... (go for src="http://www.example.com/picture1.jpg" or use a CDN to serve those images).

I recommend emailonacid to test your emails.

Comment: Btw: when using a gmail client without a gmail account they mess up your html when they convert your code. That's just usual nexus and gmail stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set width and height attributes for your images. I.e:

```
<img height="50" width="100" src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add display : inline- block for this to show properly for all image tags

```
<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/sprk_20180304_001.png"  style="display:block" width="100" height="50" />
```

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the code which is given in the screenshot with the following code:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxnWi.png)

---

```
  <tr class="grid">
                <td style="font-size: 25px; line-height: 22px;padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;font-weight: bold;text-align: center;">
                <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td width="39%" valign="top" align="left"></td>
                <td width="9%" align="left" valign="top" style="text-align:right;"><img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" /></td>
                <td width="4%" align="left" valign="top" style="text-align:center; vertical-align:middle;">/</td>
                <td width="9%" align="left" valign="top" style="text-align:left;"><img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" /></td>
                <td width="39%" valign="top" align="left"></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
                 <!--<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/grid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />/<img src="OUTBOUND_EMAILS/US/tgrid_20180304_001.png" style="height: auto;" />-->
                </td>
              </tr>
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Just check it once, are your all images on server? if no, please upload all images properly and check it again. after this just define the actual image size in image tag. for eg:


       <img width="---" style="height: auto;">

Always apply "alt" in the image tag for eg:

 <img width="---" style="height: auto;" alt="">