# css for HTML Email content not getting applied in gmail

Tags: css, html-table, html-email

I am trying to prepare mark up for an HTML email content. I have a table as shown below. The styles for the table are not getting applied when viewed in gmail(mobile and web) applications. Also the styles for this table are not getting applied when tested in apple mail. Can anyone please help.

https://jsfiddle.net/Anifa/puyddvmy/

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%" id="txn-info-container" style="padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px">
    <tr>
        <td width="25">
        </td>
        <td width="550">
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>label</td>
                        <td>Value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>label</td>
                        <td>value</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>label</td>
                        <td>value</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
        <td width="25">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

#txn-info-container table {
    max-width: 550px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F7F6F6;
    border-top: 1px solid #dfdddc;
}
#txn-info-container table td {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdddc;
    font-family: 'Roboto', 'Arial', 'Helvetica';
    font-size: 12px;
    /* text-indent: 10px; */
    Margin-left: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    #txn-info-container table  {
    Margin-left: 0px!important;
    }
}
```

Note : I am writing all the css in style tag and inlining it programatically using inline-css node module package. All the head and style tags gets removed and only the inlined css styles apply

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? Gmail tends to strip out much of styling properties for security and accessibility reasons.

Comment: Apply inline css for gmail (email) templates...
Like this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49556424/images-not-loading-properly-in-gmail-using-html-template-on-samsung-galaxy-note

Comment: @SarvanKumar Am indeed inlining the css programatically using inline-css node package

Comment: Ok, Which language used to generate email ?

Comment: Otherwise add full code of the html (email template)...

Comment: @SarvanKumar Here is my full html code - https://codeshare.io/aypp10

Comment: @JamesWong Am trying to read a table from the ck-editor, display it within the txn-info-container, add styles to it through css. This is working in all email clients except gmail and for apple mail

Comment: @SarvanKumar JS Fiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/Anifa/puyddvmy/

Comment: @AnUser, ok let me check.

Comment: @SarvanKumar Please let me know if you figured out something

Comment: @AnUser, Okay, I am working on it.

Comment: @AnUser, Please check my answer, its working fine in my end...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inline styles like this...

https://codeshare.io/GAEng8

```html
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="dummy" bgcolor="#F7F6F6" style="border: 1px solid #dfdddc;border-collapse: collapse;border-left:0;border-right:0;">
  <tr>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdddc;height: 30px;line-height: 30px;font-family: \'Roboto\', \'Arial\', \'Helvetica\';font-size: 12px;padding-left: 10px;">Label</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdddc;height: 30px;line-height: 30px;font-family: \'Roboto\', \'Arial\', \'Helvetica\';font-size: 12px;padding-left: 10px;">Value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdddc;height: 30px;line-height: 30px;font-family: \'Roboto\', \'Arial\', \'Helvetica\';font-size: 12px;padding-left: 10px;">label</td>
    <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdddc;height: 30px;line-height: 30px;font-family: \'Roboto\', \'Arial\', \'Helvetica\';font-size: 12px;padding-left: 10px;">value</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="height: 30px;line-height: 30px;font-family: \'Roboto\', \'Arial\', \'Helvetica\';font-size: 12px;padding-left: 10px;">label</td>
    <td style="height: 30px;line-height: 30px;font-family: \'Roboto\', \'Arial\', \'Helvetica\';font-size: 12px;padding-left: 10px;">value</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Its working in gmail as well...

[image]

Comment: Yes this worked. Thank you.But This particular table comes from a ck-editor where client enters his data. I cannot tell customer to add this code when they try to enter the data. Is there a backend way to achieve this, instead of front-end i.e adding in the html style attribute?

Comment: #dummy is the only table when user enters dynamically ?

Comment: This table is the only place user entered the details means you need to create this table (dynamically) from which language to send the mail

Comment: yes correct. That is the only table, where user enters data in table format.

Comment: if you use php for that email.
You need to get only values (inside td) to array.
using foreach to add the values into td.
then echo it in the html...

Comment: Thank you. i wil recommend that this table should be created dynamically if not will convince them to enter the styles within the table. Thanks a lot for your help and suggestion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169578/discussion-between-sarvan-kumar-and-an-user).

Answer (score 4):

You cant use style by id or class inside the email, if you want to style your email you must set the style inside tags.

For simple example:

```
<a style="color:white;background:black;padding:20px;">This Link</a>
```

and do not forget to set Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8 on your header.

Comment: That was what I was doing. I am writing all the css in style tag and inlining it programatically using inline-css node module package. All the head and style tags gets removed and only the inlined css styles apply

Comment: Can you just use manually tag style without inline-CSS node module package? 


because I also have tried various ways to make my email style is not on all tags but all unreadable and one of his way just by putting in the tag