# I used pchart created a piechart by "pPie". but using "base64_encode" to encode the png image.I got a wrong code

Tags: php, html, base64, encode, pchart

I used pchart created a piechart by "pPie". and used "base64_encode" to encode the png image.

```
$code = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image_path));
$html = $html . "<td><img src='data:image/png;base64," . $code . "'/></td>\n";
```

The html can't display my image.I have encoded the image by online tool,I got a different code. but when I used same function to deal with other image(a line chart and a bar chart created by pchart), it worked.Do you why and how to resolve it? Thank you very much.

Comment: Why are you base64 encoding the image. Would it not be simpler just to put the path to the image in the src attribute

Comment: @RiggsFolly Because I want to make an html file as content of email, I want the image display directly in the email.but I can't put the image online.

Comment: This answer may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/9110164/2310830