# How to display QR code of a string in gmail

Tags: java, email, gmail, sendgrid

I have an HTML template with `<img>` tag to display a QR code representation of a user ID, for that I simply used DATA URL technique `src="data:image/png;base64, base64String` as suggested by **https://sendgrid.com/blog/embedding-images-emails-facts/** under the section **Inline Embedding (Base64 Encoding)**.

This is working in outlook, but there seems to be a problem for Gmail. What is the best way to display this QR code in email clients, especially in Gmail. Note that, I do not have an actual image file as the QR is generated from the user ID, at most I just have the byte array representing the QR image.

I am using sendgrid to send the emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/29205203/2017536
Here is how this problem can be solved using javax.mail package

```
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

 private void sendMail(String to, String subject, String bodyPlainText, String bodyHtml, String contentId, String base64Image) {
    try {
        MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
        message.setSubject(subject);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));

        MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        textPart.setContent(bodyPlainText, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(bodyHtml, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        Multipart multiPart = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

        // create a new imagePart and add it to multipart so that the image is inline attached in the email
        byte[] rawImage = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Image);
        BodyPart imagePart = new MimeBodyPart();
        ByteArrayDataSource imageDataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(rawImage,"image/png");

        imagePart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(imageDataSource));
        imagePart.setHeader("Content-ID", "<qrImage>");
        imagePart.setFileName("someFileName.png");

        multiPart.addBodyPart(imagePart);
        multiPart.addBodyPart(textPart);
        multiPart.addBodyPart(htmlPart);

        message.setContent(multiPart);

        mailSender.send(message);
    } catch (MessagingException exception) {
        //log error
    }
}
```

And in your html template you should have `<img src="cid:qrImage" alt="qr code">`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this situation some time ago and was able to handle it using an API that returns an image/png content type.
Try this link https://goqr.me/api/, it will help you.
Example:

```html
<img src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?size=150x150&data=MYTEST" width="150" />
```

If you need use sensitive data, you need to encrypt it.