# Is there a way to hide blocked html images in Email Newsletters/Signatures?

Tags: html, image, email, html-email

Ive created an email signature with a few images. Most email programs block these or ask for permission. In this case the Images are displayed by a blank box. Is there a way to get rid of said boxes if the client blocks html?

Comment: You can't overcome a security feature like image block. It is set by administrators and users. You could style the `TD` and the `ALT` to offer an alternative styled signature to display so it's not a blank box. This would be overlayed with the image you want to show if images are not blocked by default.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to insert images as base64 [Data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) (if your images are relatively small). You can use [this online converter](https://ezgif.com/image-to-datauri) to generate Data URI for your images.

Here is an example:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAA
ANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4
//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU
5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Alternatively, you can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures/9110164#9110164) about embedded attachments:

```
<img src="cid:0123456789">
```

Comment: Base64 doesn't have good support. This is not a good recommendation https://www.caniemail.com/features/image-base64/

Comment: @Nathan true. embedded attachments a better option.

Comment: @vovchisko True! I discovered by accident, after having gone the "src=" route with a data URI that Gmail webmail does not support image URI's. It was working fine with all of my other platforms but I happened to check the webmail and was surprised to see Gmail stripped it out. I wound up changing to inline attachments with "src=cid:" instead. Inline URI's would be much nicer but it is what it is.