# How to display qrcode image in email?

Tags: php, html, symfony4, qr-code

I am using endroid/qr-code `https://github.com/endroid/qr-code` to generate QrCode.
Now I need to send this QR to my email too.

I have used following codes:

```
    $result = Builder::create()
        ->writer(new PngWriter())
        ->writerOptions([])
        ->data("This ist test page.")
        ->encoding(new Encoding('UTF-8'))
        ->size(200)
        ->margin(10)
        ->roundBlockSizeMode(new RoundBlockSizeModeMargin())
        ->logoPath($webPath)
        ->labelText('SCAN')
        ->build();

    return $result->getDataUri();
```

At my email twig page I have

```
<img src = {{ $return_from_result_getDataUri }} >
```

I am getting broken img from above line.

When I use {{ $return_from_result_getDataUri }}, this gives me `data:image/png;base64.....` text displayed.

Can anybody help me here.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us exactly what "broken image" is and also an example of a data URI that is "broken".

Comment: I already got the answer to my question. Broken image means image not showing. data URI is returning base64 encoded text as I have written in my question.

Comment: I dont know why people here in SO likes to close questions often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Embedding images with Data URI in Emails is still not optimal and many email clients don't support it at all.

See [this analysis from Campaign Monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/embedded-images-in-html-email/) showing many clients not rendering the Data URI image.

I strongly suggest you to upload the QR code somewhere and then link it as a normal image.

If your services are hosted on AWS, you can use S3.

Otherwise you can use free services but I don't have any experience with them. This is the first result I found: https://apidocs.imgur.com/

*PS: Just adding that you might be missing some double quotes as well in your code.*

```
<img src="{{ $return_from_result_getDataUri }}" >
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<img src = {{ $return_from_result_getDataUri }} >
```

In PHP, we would write the above as follows

```
<img src="<?php echo $return_from_result_getDataUri; ?>" >
```

But this may not work with all email clients. There are two methods to overcome this issue.

Method 1:
As Andrea Mentioned, Save the file somewhere

```
 $result->saveToFile(`__DIR__`.'/qrcode.png');
```

then use the url in html img tag.

```
<img src="<?php echo $fullImageUrl; ?>">
```

Method 2:
Embed the image as an attachment and Refer it using cid(content id)

This is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures#9110164)

Comment: Thanks I followed method 1