# Cakephp logo in mail

Tags: php, cakephp

im trying to set up an email.

Now everything is working fine however i cannot seem to get the images into my email.

I have used the following code:

```
    <?php echo $this->Html->image("udlejning-img/Udlej-logo.jpg", array(
    "alt" => "logo",
    'url' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index')
)); ?>
```

However this did not seem to work (note that i am using this code somewhere else where the picture is displayed normally)

Comment: Do you want insert image in mail body?

Comment: Yes That is the end game

Comment: Is this helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390138/insert-image-in-mail-body ?

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari sadly not since im using cakephp to send my email

Comment: Have you checked the docs? http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/email.html#sending-attachments

Comment: @ndm this explains how to attach it to the mail not how to set it into the actual mail body

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set "fullBase" true. Otherwise the image url will be relative to your server

```
<?php echo $this->Html->image("udlejning-img/Udlej-logo.jpg", array(
"alt" => "logo",
'url' => array('controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index'),
'fullBase' => true
));?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. this will give you the absolute image path as well as absolute url for your logo.

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->image("udlejning-img/Udlej-logo.jpg", array(
        "alt" => "logo",
        'fullBase' => true
    )), array(
    'controller' => 'home', 'action' => 'index', 'full_base' => true
), array( 'escape' => false));

?>
```

[reference.](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3aimage)