# How to include an image in a php HTML email?

Tags: php, html, email

I want avoid this solution

```
<img src='https://DOMAIN.TLD/images/link-image.jpg' alt='' />
```

because most email clients (such as Thunderbid) will return a message like this

```
email client has blocked remote content in this message
```

Are there alternative to include an image in an html email without using
the image remote link above ?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no other way if you use php mail. Here is a contribution to it that has already dealt with the topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390138/insert-image-in-mail-body

Comment: Does this answer your question? [base64 encoded images in email signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9110091/base64-encoded-images-in-email-signatures)

Comment: Data URLs which would include base64 encoded image directly inside the emails are a possibility and would work well for browser based email clients. I am not sure about data URL support in desktop email clients.