# Attaching an uploaded image in PHP mail

Tags: php, email, file-upload, jpeg, attachment

Hi ladies and gentlemen I am hoping you will be able to help me with this.

I have created a web form where people can enter registration information and upload an image to our server for a photo contest. The uploader works great and an email gets sent with the registration information but I am having a hard time getting the uploaded image to attach to the email. I was hoping someone would be able to help me figure this out. The form and processor page are located in the same directory and the image get placed in a subfolder called upload. Here is what I have so far which does not work for attaching image. It give me an error:

```
    <?php
  if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
   || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
   && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000))
 {
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";


if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
  else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  echo "\nFile submitted.";
  }
}
}
else
{
  echo "Invalid file";
 }


        // DO THE MAILING HERE

        $fields = array('name','address','city','state','zip','phone','photo','location');

        //$to = "cboyd@dacc.edu";
        $to2 = "ampeck@earthlink.net";
        $subject = "Sustainability Photo Contest";
        $headers =  "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"";

        $headers .='Content-type: image/jpeg; charset=iso-8859-1' . PHP_EOL;
        $headers .= "From: noreply@dacc.edu\r\n" . "X-Mailer: php";
        $bound_text =   "DACCreport";
 $bound =   "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
 $bound_last =  "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";



  $message =    "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
.$bound;

  $message .=   "Content-Type: image/jpeg; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
."Photo Contest entry\r\n"
.$bound;



  $file =   file_get_contents($_FILES["file"]["name"]);

 $message .=    "Content-Type: image/jpeg; name="($_FILES["file"]["name"])"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-disposition: attachment; file="($_FILES["file"]["name"])"\r\n"
."\r\n"
.chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
.$bound_last; 

        $greet = "The following was submitted on " . date("F j, Y, g:i a") . "<p>";

        $body = $greet;
        //$cn = 1;

        foreach($fields as $efield) {
            if(isset($_POST[$efield])) {


                if($efield == "name") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Name: </strong>" . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif($efield == "address") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Address:</strong> " . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif($efield == "city") {
                    $body.= "<strong>City:</strong> " . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif ($efield == "state") {
                    $body.= "<strong>State: </strong>" . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif ($efield == "phone") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Daytime Phone Number: </strong>" . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif ($efield == "photo") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Name of Photo: </strong>" . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif ($efield == "location") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Location where Photo was taken:</strong> " . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";

                }
            }
        }

        //mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
        mail($to2, $subject, $body, $headers);

        ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to attach and show image in mail using php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606588/how-to-attach-and-show-image-in-mail-using-php)

Comment: Not quite PeeHaa, doesn't deal with uploading. I figured it out though

Comment: From your question: "The uploader works great and an email gets sent with the registration information but I am having a hard time getting the uploaded image to attach to the email."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I came up with. It took a little finessing based on the upload code and attaching files information. Plus I ran into a problem with  the headers, but I managed to get it to work and it works well.

```
    <?php
 if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
 || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
 && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000))
   {
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
     {
     echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
     }
   else
     {
     echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
     echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
     echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";


     if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
       {
       echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
       }
     else
       {
       move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
       "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
       echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
       echo "<br> File submitted.";
       }
     }
   }
 else
   {
   echo "Invalid file";
   }


            // DO THE MAILING HERE
     $filename = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
 ;       
 $to3 =     
 $to4 = 
 $subject =     'Sustainability Photo Contest';
 $bound_text =  "dacc1231";
 $bound =   "--".$bound_text."\r\n";
 $bound_last =  "--".$bound_text."--\r\n";

 $headers =     "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"
."Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"$bound_text\"". PHP_EOL;
 $headers .=    "From: noreply@dacc.edu\r\n";



 $fields = array('name','address','city','state','zip','phone','photo','location');

        $greet = "The following was submitted on " . date("F j, Y, g:i a") . "<p>";

        $body = $greet;
        //$cn = 1;

        foreach($fields as $efield) {
            if(isset($_POST[$efield])) {


                if($efield == "name") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Name: </strong>" . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif($efield == "address") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Address:</strong> " . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif($efield == "city") {
                    $body.= "<strong>City:</strong> " . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif ($efield == "state") {
                    $body.= "<strong>State: </strong>" . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif ($efield == "phone") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Daytime Phone Number: </strong>" . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif ($efield == "photo") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Name of Photo: </strong>" . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";
                } elseif ($efield == "location") {
                    $body.= "<strong>Location where Photo was taken:</strong> " . $_POST[$efield] . "<p>";

                }
            }
        }

 $message =     "If you can see this MIME than your client doesn't accept MIME types!\r\n"
.$bound;

 $message .=    "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n"
."Here is a Submission for the Photo Contest\r\n" .$body ."\r\n"

.$bound;     
 $file =     file_get_contents($filename); 

 $message .=    "Content-Type: image/jpg; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"
."Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n"
."Content-disposition: attachment; file=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"
."\r\n"
.chunk_split(base64_encode($file))
.$bound_last;

 if(mail($to3, $subject, $message,  $headers)
 &&
 mail($to4, $subject, $message,$headers ))
 {
 echo '<br> MAIL SENT';
 } else {
 echo '<br> MAIL FAILED';
 }





        ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $files = $_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'];
    $filename = $_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'];    
    $fp = fopen($files[$i],"rb");
    $data = fread($fp,filesize($files[$i]));
    fclose($fp);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $message .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".basename($filename[$i])."\"\n" . 
                "Content-Description: ".basename($filename[$i])."\n" .
                "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"".basename($filename[$i])."\"; size=".filesize($files[$i]).";\n" . 
                "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
```

You can attach file without moving it to the server using this code.

Comment: thanks for replying. I ended up figuring it out this morning with a little trial and error.